# Current Required to Power Pi Via 5V GPIO

Tags: pi-3, alternative-power

So for the project I am working on I am attempting to power a Raspiberry Pi 3 through the 5V Pin along the header.  This is the setup I have:

[image: Pi Setup]
The large orange box on the right is a 12V power supply, which runs through a [7805SR-C Voltage Regulator](http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/7805SR-C/?qs=35WhQNrE6p3r8osawIMOlg%3D%3D)(circled in red) to supply a 5V output to power the Pi.

My problem right now is that when attempting to power up the unit it gets stuck booting.  Basically it will start to boot, get to one point, and shut down and start booting again.  I'm sure this is because it isn't getting enough power (positive in fact, I was having the little "Not enough power" lightning bolt showing on my monitor) which may be due to the voltage regulators only outputting at 500mA.

As you can see, I have two voltage regulators set up.  Currently I have nothing running from the 5V output of the second one.  Would I be able to hook up the other 5V Pin to the other regulator without essentially blowing up the Pi?

I'm not exactly electrical savvy, I was kind of just handed this and told, "make it work" :|

I'm unsure if the extra voltage will be too much for the Pi or if it will be fine because of the low current from the regulators.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you think that powering the Pi through the GPIO will require less current than powering it through the micro USB plug. The simple fact is that your power supply is insufficient.

Comment: I don't think it will require less current.  I've just read that when supplying power via the GPIO you bypass the onboard fuse or whatever that the pi had built in through the micro USB.  As such I want to make sure adding more power won't blow up the Pi

Comment: You can't power it from both the GPIO and micro USB. get a different regulator.

Comment: I'm not trying to power it from both the GPIO and the USB.  I'm asking if I can plug in more voltage to the other 5V Pin.  I am currently sending power through Pin 4, but Pin 2 is not connected to anything.  If my only fix is to get a different regulator I will I just want to see if there are other solutions first.

Comment: @SteveRobillard if my only option is to get a new Regulator, what is the maximum current I can send over the GPIO pins?

Comment: Whatever that is, looks like someone spent a fair amount of time making, why would you then bypass the protection provided by the micro USB power port? The Pi is only going to pull as much current as is required.

Comment: As I said above, I didn't put this together.  I am a programmer, not any sort of electrical engineer.  My boss decided this is how he wanted it set up and then threw it at me and told me to fix it when it wouldn't work.

Comment: If your 7805 doesn't have a heat sink then add one.  Better still replace the 7805 with an inexpensive UBEC which will convert a range of voltages to a Pii safe 5V and supply enough amps to power the Pi.

Comment: @joan does your recommendation of the UBEC change if I mention my power supply is 5A/60W?  Or would that still work with something [like this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1385)?

Comment: 5A/60W suggests a 12V power supply.  If so a UBEC is fine, it will handle roughly 5.5V to 28V and convert to 5V at up to say 4 amps (although I would try to limit current draw to about 2 amps, which is more than enough for the Pi and any likely peripherals).